# i want to call a fragment which is present in RecyclerView through a fragment by using image button OnClickListener(Java)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, onclick, fragment

[These are my fragments along with adapter and other required classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APtCY.png)
[These are my layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McftH.png)

**Home(fragment)**
`(where the Image Button is placed)

```
package com.example.fragment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Switch;


public class Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Image Button cricket_btn,football_btn,athletics_btn,badminton_btn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View v = inflater. Inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       cricket_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.cric_btn);
       football_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.foot_btn);
       badminton_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.bad_btn);
       athletics_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.athl_btn);
       return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.cric_btn:
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                Fragment_Cricket myFragment = new Fragment_Cricket();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace
                        (R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }
}`
```

I want open a fragment which present in the recycler view with the Image Button in Home(which is also a fragment). How can I do that

I tried google, chat GPT also stack Overflow but didn't got any solution so here i am with my first ever question/comment expecting a helping hand '-'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' know if i well understood your problem.
Tecnically, you want to open a fragment inside a fragment clicking a button?

First of all you have to add a view in your fragment_home.xml in this way:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            />
```

Then, you can set a click listener event on a button or do it as you already have done, example:

```
athletics_btn.setOnClickListener(setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 call_fragment();
             }
         });
```

And then you can open a fragment from fragment in this way:

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
            Fragment_Cricket myFragment = new Fragment_Cricket();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace
                    (R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "idFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Try and let me know if works.

+++++

AFTER GIT REPO DOWNLOAD:

my home fragment implementation:

```
//todo: removed click listener implementation in fragment.
//public class Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
public class Home extends Fragment
{
    ImageButton cricket_btn,football_btn,athletics_btn,badminton_btn;
    //Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       cricket_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.cric_btn);
       football_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.foot_btn);
       badminton_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.bad_btn);
       athletics_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.athl_btn);

       //todo added this method.
       setButtonsClickListeners();

       return v;

    }

    /*
    todo: you can remove this!
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.cric_btn:
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                Fragment_Cricket myFragment = new Fragment_Cricket();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace
                        (R.id.fragment_container2, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

    }
    */

    //todo new method.
    private void setButtonsClickListeners()
    {
        setSingleClickListener(cricket_btn, new Fragment_Cricket());
        setSingleClickListener(football_btn, new Fragment_Football());
        setSingleClickListener(badminton_btn, new Fragment_Badminton());
        setSingleClickListener(athletics_btn, new Fragment_Athletics());
    }

    //todo new method.
    private void setSingleClickListener(@NonNull final ImageButton toManage, @NonNull final Fragment fragment)
    {
        toManage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                openFragment(fragment);
            }
        });
    }

    //todo new method.
    private void openFragment(@NonNull final Fragment fragment)
    {
        final AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        if(activity != null){
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container2, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "null activity?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

my fragment cricket implementation:

```
//todo: my implementation of this fragment.
public class Fragment_Cricket extends Fragment
{
    private ImageButton btnInfo = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__cricket, container, false);
        declareViewElements(view);
        setViewElements();
        return view;
    }

    private void declareViewElements(@NonNull final View view)
    {
        btnInfo = view.findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
    }

    private void setViewElements()
    {
        btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "do what you want", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No its not working, i got the problem. The button isn't working. what to do now.

Comment: the fragment i want is in the recycler which is again in a fragment.                                                 fragment_i_want_open(fragment_cricket) <is in> -->recycler_view <which is in> --> another_fragment(Sports_fragment). Actually i didn't created activities, playing with fragment only and got stuck.

Comment: can you post, in the main answer, the XML layout files, or, if you want, share me a git repo . thanks

Comment: https://github.com/ikkoo148/Sport-Application  just learned how to upload it thanks for helping.

Comment: sorry, can you explain me the problem?
i have runned the application, and it seems to works.
try to explain me what to see.

Comment: When you clicked on cricket_btn which is on homepage(fragment)did it navigate you to the cricket fragment. I tried puting a toast on button but it didn't worked.

Comment: i don't have permission for commit my changes, so i post my change in answer. you find my change with TODO flag.

Comment: maybe you should find a pull request in yout github.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Just one more Question as i don't know any android developer. " is it good to use fragment like i am using?" Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: yes it think yes. you have an activity that manage a list of fragments, and depends on the user interaction, you invoke the desidered fragment .